# How to rearrange an array by another array of indexes in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Given the array:

```
int data[5] = {data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4]}
```

…and another array with indexes:

```
int idx[5] = {3,1,0,2,4}
```

What is the fastest way to rearrange the `data[5]` array, so that the resulting (sorted) array becomes:

```
data[5] = {data[3],data[1],data[0],data[2],data[4]}
```

Comment: the best can be O(n) ,

Comment: can the space complexity  be O(n) ?or shud be less than that?

Comment: @polasairam the best method I know is to first copy the origin array, and then use for loop to assign. O(n) space complexity is acceceptable if I get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array in pairs based on the indexes: for any comparison and reordering operation you do in the reference array, move the corresponding indexes in the other array as such as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `temp` array and fill it in your `idx`'s order with your `data`'s data

```
int temp[5];

for(int i = 0 ; i< 5 ; i++){
    temp[i] = data[idx[i]];
}
```

Comment: It is evident that the problem is to do the task without intermediate containers.

Comment: **evident**? I just read the question again and didnt find any think about not using intermediate container!

Comment: What is the problem to write temp[i] = data[idx[i]];?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, it would be much trickier without *any* other container, at least to keep track of processed indices

Comment: @VladfromMoscow we both have seen easier things that became question for people, the thing that you want is more beautiful but it is not what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in-place rearrangment?

```
int idx[5] = {3,1,0,2,4}
int idx2[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    idx2[idx[i]] = i;
}
// we have array int idx2[5] = {2,1,3,0,4}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    if (i == idx[i]) continue;

    std::swap(data[i], data[idx[i]]);
    idx[idx2[idx[i]]] = i; // Update indices list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the simplest and fastest way is to use a temporary array of same size, save data to it, and then reset data with proper indexes.

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    sv_data[i] = data[i];
}
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    data[i] = sv_data[idx[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is **not** the fastest.
Nevertheless, space complexity is *O*(1).

```
int data[] = {'c', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'e'}; // input array
int idx[] = {3, 1, 0, 2, 4};    // sorted index
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (idx[i] != i) {
        int temp = data[i]; // save a datum
        int src = idx[i];
        int dst = i;
        do {    // cyclic permutation
            data[dst] = data[src];  // move a datum
            idx[dst] = dst; // replace an index
            dst = src;
            src = idx[dst];
        } while (src != i);
        data[dst] = temp;   // restore
        idx[dst] = dst;
    }
}
```

`data[]` is rearranged as below.

```
(c, b, d, a, e)
(_, b, d, a, e) {c}
(a, b, d, _, e) {c}
(a, b, _, d, e) {c}
(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Where, { } is `temp`.
`idx[]` is rearranged to (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) at last.